# Not able to save cookie in browser using react but the backend code work with postman and save cookie inside postman's cookie as well as in browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, setcookie, react-fullstack

I got the token inside the cookies when hit the code from postman but didn't get when hit the same api with react. this is my code

for backend
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQMaf.png)

```
    
export const signin = async(req,res,next)=>{
        try{
         const user = await User.findOne({name:req.body.name, })
         if(!user) return next(createError(404, "User not found"))
         const isCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password) // 2nd parameter is password save in our db means user.password
         if(!isCorrect) return next(createError(400,"Wrong credentials"))
         const token = jwt.sign({id:user._id}, process.env.JWT_KEY)// you can send any user information like name, id and a secrete key
    // for not sending password with user details
         const {password, ...others} = user._doc// this seperate details like password and otherdetails and ._doc is used to prevent to geeting unwanted details
            console.log("    hi from auth")
            // res.cookie("access_token","bar")
    // we can send this token to user [00:42:07]
    // we use cookies and for this we have to install library cookie-parser and use it in index.js
        res.cookie("access_token", token,{ // parameters are cookie name and token
            httpOnly:true, // make our application more nsecure means other third party scripts not able to use cookie
            // secure:true
        }).status(200).json(others);
        console.log("cookie from auth",req.cookies.access_token)
        }
        catch (e){
         next(e)
        }
     }
```

---

```
    This code going to save cookie in side the browser while hitting the api with postman
       app.get("/set-cookie", (req,res)=>{
         res.cookie("access_token",token)
         res.send("cookie is set")
    })

    // get cookie from the browser
    app.get("/get-cookie",(req,res)=>{
        console.log(req.cookies)//contains an object of all the cookies in key-value pairs
        res.send(req.cookies)
    })


    // delete cookie from the browser
    app.get("/del-cookie",(req,res)=>{
        res.clearCookie("foo");
        res.send("cookie has been deleted")
    })
```

---

for react [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fmef.png)

```
    function Signin(){
        const [name, setName] = useState("");
        const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
        const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
    
    // for using login start we need dispatch function
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
    // [01:54:20]
        const handleLogin= async(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
    
    // [02:05:27]
            dispatch(loginStart()); // not passing anything no have any payload
            try{
                const res=await axios.post(`http://localhost:8800/api/auth/signin`,{name,password}) // url and crendentials like sending name and password
                console.log("res--------", res)
                dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data)); //  passing res.data as a payload
            }catch(err){
                dispatch(loginFailure())
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
```

I debug the code inspect the code but didn't get the error

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provided, it seems like you are unable to console log the cookies when calling the get-cookie route with your frontend when you are signed in, but it works when using postman.

If I am correct and you have set up CORS properly, this should be an easy fix.

Just include the cookie on your axios request with the withCredentials option.

```js
await axios.get("your-route/", {withCredentials: true});
```